# biblatex does not print book in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

Good day to all!

Today, I'm using beamer and biblatex.

In the bibliography frame, I want to print book references. But, I didn't obtain the desire result.

What I have done is at the end, into the respective bibliography frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{abc6,
  title={The Quantum Theory of Atoms in Molecules: From Solid State to DNA     and Drug Design},
  author={Matta, C.F. and Boyd, R.J.},
  isbn={9783527307487},
  url={https://books.google.com.co/books?id=7mE9rwz6P04C},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Wiley}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Bibliograf\'ia}
    %\printbibheading
    \printbibliography
    %\printbibsection{book}{Libros}
    %\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibintoc,title={Another try}]
    %\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Fuentes de libros}]
    %\printbibliography[nottype=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Otras fuentes}]
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: As far as I'm aware `\printbibsection{book}{Libros}` is a construction that is defined in the friggery class, so in other document classes, it will not work. The problem here is that you have not cited anything. Either cite the works you would like to appear in the bibliography using `\cite` at appropriate times, or issue a `\nocite{foo}` (so the entry is silently added to the bibliography) or even `\nocite{*}` to add all entries in your `.bib` file to the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you @moewe ,  for enlighten me on that silly mistake. If you want, please, put a brief answer to check it. Thank you again and have a good day : )

Comment: Normally, questions like this where the answer is that something quite ovious is missing tend to get closed, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a missing `\cite` or `\nocite` command. A problem which has since been resolved by the OP (see comments above).